# Setting up webcam streaming on Amazon EC2 w/ Ubuntu & Wowza

Tags: amazon-ec2, webcam, wowza, broadcasting

I've been trying for a long time now, to figure out how to set up an application on Wowza that accepts webcam streams (Flash) and broadcast these streams online for many people to connect/see.

Is this at all possible? If yes, do you have any info. on how to do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Sincerely,
Mikal

**EDIT:**
If it's Amazon EC2 or another server isnt that relavant. I got the same problems locally. The problem is regarding building an application that accepts and broadcasts incoming webcam streams.